# Intellisense like SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to implement intellisence suggestion engine in my web application, so that the following table

```
COMPANIES (
      id           BIGSERIAL    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      name         VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
      )
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name ON companies USING BTREE (name);
```

row with name

```
'Mysterious unicorn startup'
```

I can search it by name using query with first two (what is the best number?) letters from  words that are in the name. Number of words will be variable and query should also suggest row if i type beginning of the first word.

so that the following queries will return this row:

```
suggest("mysteri");
```

will match:
    '**Mysteri**ous unicorn startup'

```
suggest("myunst");
```

will match:
 '**My**sterious **un**icorn **st**artup'

```
suggest("myst");
```

will match:
'**My**sterious unicorn **st**artup'

The question is: How can i write a sql SELECT request that will work for all these cases?

Comment: What is the question actually? The best way to optimize an index? "The best number" of letters from words to search?

Comment: @KamilG just edited it. The question is: How can i write a sql SELECT request that will work for all these cases?

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a LIKE comparison:

```
SELECT id, name FROM Companies WHERE Name LIKE 'myst%'
```

However, don't just take the user input and append it onto your query as this opens you up to sql injection attacks.  You'll want to use a parameter when building your query.

Comment: This will do like query against a single word. I need to be able to do like by 2 or more word beginnings.

Comment: I hope you didn't downvote me for that.  Your question is confusing at best.  I'm curious how you expect to break apart a single parameter (like 'myst') into two separate values.  But overall, I think you should look into full-text indexing.  This allows the database to understand your column as many words as opposed to a single value.  You could programmatically pull things apart and search for different things, but full text indexing allows the database to do this work for you.